# Setting parameters for an API using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, user-input, rest

I am tasked with writing code that allows a user to input a number, and get a list of all authors in their list order whose submission_count is greater than the users input number. Below is what I have so far. I am unsure of how to set a parameter to user being greater then user input. This is the first time I have interacted with REST API and json, so if there are any other recommendations you have about my code or ways to code this task I am more then open to suggestions.

[image]

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Can you please add more details about server logic, does it expect submission_count in payload?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have server logic in place that handles `submission_count`.

You can use `input` function to take input from user then add 1 to the number ensuring it to be greater than number submitted by user. Finally add it to the dictionary

```
import requests
def getUsernames(threshold):
   count = int(input("Enter a number: ")) + 1
   param = {"submission_count":count}
   response = requests.get('your-url-here', params=param)
```

Comment: I ran what you post and am getting error NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Comment: have you imported requests module?

Comment: i beleive so yes using import requests

Comment: def getUsernames(threshold):
   import requests
count = int(input("Enter a number: ")) + 1
param = {"submission_count":count}

response = requests.get('https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/article_users?page=<pageNumber>', params=param)

Comment: First, why are you imoorting in function and not on top? I mean is it intentional?

Comment: I have edited the answer, feel free to upvote if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I am getting a new error File "Solution.py", line 22, in getUsernames
    count = int(input("Enter a number: ")) + 1
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: it suggest that you are missing some bracket or have some error, can you paste complete code for this function?